# The-nature-of-sar-pixel-value-vs-of-panchromatic-pixel-value

Tags: remote-sensing, electromagnetism, radar

When we compare sentinel-1 SAR orthorectified 8-bit image vs a very high resolution panchromatic 8-bit image, the panchromatic cells are a resemblance of signal amplitude in an 8-bit scale (0-255). And, if I've got it right, each of the SAR cells is a resemblance of how much amplitude the antenna is recorded (of the wave height and not length).

Given the below image, **which are on the same extents**, each of the SAR pixels (cells) covers the same area as for 17689 panchromatic cells (so 6 SAR cells cover ~ 106400 pan. cells ).

But the question is: a 20x20m pixel covers a lot of different materials (cars, land, water, cement and etc.), so what constitutes which number (how much amplitude) goes to each of the 20x20m cells.

**Is it an average of all the incoming amplitudes to the SAR antenna?**

**Is it the strongest amplitude that wins the pixel value?**

**Or a different story?** It would be much obliged if you attach some additional reference to your answer.

*I've already asked this question on [another forum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422875/the-nature-of-sar-pixel-value-vs-of-panchromatic-pixel-value) but no one has answered it.*

[image]